# Python PyQt5: How to change the color of QLabel if QLineEdit is empty?

Tags: python, colors, pyqt5, qlineedit, qlabel

With

```
myQLineEdit.textChanged.connect(
lambda: myQLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel { color: green}"))
```

I can change the text color while I'm typing. 
How can I change the text color if the QLineEdit is blank?

Comment: you have to write function which checks text length in QLineEdit (and change color) and use it instead of `lambda`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textChanged` signal sends the text as a parameter, so you can use that to switch between colours:

```
myQLineEdit.textChanged.connect(lambda text: myQLabel.setStyleSheet(
    "QLabel { color: %s}" % ('green' if text else 'red')))
```